# regex para substituir a string $_POST['field'] por $this->input->post('field') do codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, regex, phpstorm

Estou tentando encontrar um meio de substituir a sequencia `$_POST['INPUT']` por `$this->input->post('INPUT')` do *codeigniter*, no meu editor [phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html), usando o *replace* com a opção *regex* ativa.

Então, o que está entre aspas que é o nome do `input` seria mantido e eu apenas substituiria em todo o arquivo as variáveis `$_post` pela função do *codeigniter*.

Comment: Isso deve servir: \$_POST\ ['INPUT'\ ]. É só escapar as as metacaracteres com \$, \[ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use essa *regex* para capturar os caracteres que deseja, separando-os em 2 grupos.

```
\$_(.*?)\['(.*?)'\]
```

No campo de substituição use:

```
$this->\L$2->$1\('\U$2\')
```

Explicação:

A primeira *regex* capturará os valores que você deseja separando a palavra `post` no grupo 1 e a palavra `input` no grupo 2

Após isso, no campo de substituição, elas serão usadas se referenciando a `\1` como o primeiro grupo de captura e `\2` para o segundo, resultando em

```
$this->input->post('INPUT')
```

É valido lembrar que algumas *regex flavours* não permitem o uso de *modifiers* nos grupos de substituição, se esse for o caso, você pode mudar a parte de substituição para:

```
$this->input->$1\('$2\')
```

Você pode testar sua regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/SDF4GD/4)

> Como mencionado pelo usuário que perguntou nos comentarios dessa
>   resposta, o que resolveu seu problema foi:

```
\$this->input->\L$1\('\L$2\')
```

Comment: só deu um erro utilizando a string de substituição, o editor informou isso: "You have entered malformed replacement string: '$this->input->$1\('$2\')'

Comment: ps: se eu colocar uma barra no início da string de substituição ele mostra o preview da substituição mas ao invés do "input" ele coloca o nome do campo no lugar.

Comment: Use $this->\L$2->$1\('\U$2')

Comment: na verdade no php storm deu certo usando o seu mas modifiquei um pouco e funcionou direitinho ```\$this->input->\L$1\('\L$2\')```

Comment: Excelente amigo, vou alterar a resposta atualizando com a sua, cheers!

Comment: +1 interessante a implementação do `\L` e `\U` nunca havia visto.